# Acessing control in one window from another in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am making my first WPF app, a new version of my app in WPF. I have a Winforms web browser inside a WindowsFormsHost. I need to access this web browser from another Window in order to load websites from different buttons. In Winforms I used to use:

```
Form1.WebBrowser1.Navigate("website")
```

But this doesn't work in WPF. I tried this:

```
Public Class Quicksites
    Dim main As New MainWindow
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        main.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
    End Sub
```

This does not work, because the website never loads in the `WebBrowser` in the main Window.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You did not call `.Show()` on the `MainWindow` form variable named `main`. Also wondering why there is no `Handles` clause on your button's click event? Did you `Addhandler` that?

```
Public Class Quicksites
 Dim main As New MainWindow
 Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button.Click
    main.Show()
    main.WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
 End Sub
```

Comment: While this does work, it's not what I wanted. I want the website to open in the window that is already open. The reason I declared the main variable is because MainWindow.WebBrowser1 doesn't work. If I try to use that I get the error "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference." Declareing the main variable, I was able to use Webrowser1.Navigate.

Comment: Then you need the web browser control inside of that form. Or use the `Frame` control.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF use directly the WebBrowser control without the WindowsFormsHost and you should navigate using an Uri like this:

```
browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

In the xaml file being:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="browser"/>
```

Your code should work just fine.

Comment: I was using a WinForms WebBrowser because the WPF WebBrowser control is missing certain members I need to use such as "Stop" and "Print".

Comment: I think you are not using the instance that you want. If you want to use the correct webbrowser instance you need to pass it to your QuickSites class for example in the class constructor, or exactly for your code you need to pass the entire MainWindow instance. How to pass and what or using an interface with a Navigate method receiving the url is another topic like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311215/passing-variable-time-from-one-form-to-another-c-sharp/18311455#18311455.